# How to add a css property only when condition true using styled components and react?

Tags: css, reactjs

i wanted to add border property only when isOpen condition true using styled components and react.

below is my code,

```
const Wrapper = styled.div<{ $isOpen: boolean }>`
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: flex;
`;
```

How to apply border only when isOpen is true?

could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#passed-props

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grabbing an example from the home page of [styled-components](https://styled-components.com/):

```js
import styled, { css } from 'styled-components'

const Button = styled.button`
  background: transparent;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 2px solid palevioletred;
  color: palevioletred;
  margin: 0 1em;
  padding: 0.25em 1em;

  ${props =>
    props.primary &&
    css`
      background: palevioletred;
      color: white;
    `};
`
```

How you would use it in the react renderer:

```
render(
  <Container>
    <Button>Normal Button</Button>
    <Button primary>Primary Button</Button>
  </Container>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

```
const Wrapper = styled.div`    
    display: flex;

    ${({isOpen}) =>
        isOpen &&
          css`
          { 
            border: 1px solid black;
          }`
    }
`;
```